# Extracting a .zip.mime file in python 2.7

Tags: python, zip, mime

I have a .zip.mime file and I was wondering how to extract the data located in the in the zip file which is in the .mime file? Using just:

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(source_file_path, 'r')
```

does not yield any result because the file is not technically a .zip file.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "date located insize the zip file"? If you are referring to when the file was created/modified, then this post will help you.

[How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Comment: My bad, I edited the question, I hope its more clear what i want to achieve